# Scroll a Gallery widget?

Tags: android

I'm using a `Gallery` widget. I'd like to automate scrolling. Not sure if this is possible?

Gallery has a `scrollTo()` and `scrollBy()` set of methods, which I can call from a **timer** etc, but that ends up scrolling the entire gallery widget itself, not its children view content.

There must be some way to automate scrolling?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the Gallery's "onFling" wrapped in a Timer:

`bannerView.onFling(null, null, flingSpeed, 0);`

where flingSpeed is the speed you need for the gallery to move to the next item.
I'm my case I got an empirical value of -650F (for a 260x80 image plus padding).
However, because of the different screen sizes and densities, I multiply my empirical value by the screen density to get it right:

`float flingSpeed = -650F * getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density`

The empirical value is probably going to be different for you so you should adapt it to your situation.

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK it isn't possible to have a scrollable widget with the standard android SDK. But some home replacement apps provide a way to do it, like LauncherPro, ADWLauncher or Home++.

More info [here](http://www.androidcentral.com/scrollable-widgets-coming-phones-without-htc-sense-too) and [here](http://code.google.com/p/scrollable-widget-for-hpp/)

Comment: Mark means the View Widget Gallery not a Homescreen Widget.